# Можно ли определить как вызвалась пользоват. функция в PHP?

Tags: php

```
get_data('my_data');
```

или

```
$data = get_data('my_data');
```

?

Comment: Эмм... А где разница в вызове функции??

Может вас интересует, куда результат будет помещен?

Comment: Если вызывается "прямо" то результат сразу отработает в `echo $result;` если в переменную то без вывода, просто `return $result;` или можно как то иначе сделать? (без class)

Comment: хм логично, спасибо! я не очень люблю конструкции типа

<p>html tags</p><?php $any_php_code = true; ?><p>next html</p>

привычнее составить страничку в переменную скажем $out, а после сделать echo $out; или так работает медленнее? или нет разницы и кто как привык?

Comment: Ваш вопрос все еще до конца не понятен.

Попробуйте привести пример вашего кода

Comment: Запись вида

    <p>html tags</p><?php $any_php_code = true; ?><p>next html</p>

используется в шаблонах. Только обычно здесь выводятся значения переменных и результаты функции, а вся логика содержится в "основном" скрипте.

Обычно "основной" скрипт выполняет необходимые действия для получения и генерации данных для контента страницы и все это дело сохраняется, например, в переменные. Затем этот же скрипт подключает шаблоны шапки, тела и футера, в которых используются переменные, заполненные ранее. Это один из наиболее универсальных вариантов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вызывается "прямо", то результат никуда не будет присвоен. Если вы хотите его вывести, пишите

```
echo get_data('my_data');
```

или если есть поддержка "коротких тегов", то прямо в HTML

```
<?= get_data('my_data') ?>
```

Comment: Возможно вас натолкнет на решение вашего вопроса мануал по какому-нибудь шаблонизатору. Познакомьтесь, например, со [smarty][1]


  [1]: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/

Comment: Ваш метод ``html`` выведет только статический контент. Вы нигде не передаете данные в подключаемые файлы. Либо же в подключаемых файлах содержится своя логика, что явно не комильфо.

Дам подсказку: после инклуда в подключаемом файле будут доступны все переменные из текущего окружения. Например, в вашем случае в подключаемом файле будут доступны переменные $dir, $value и $method.

Также, что не очевидно, все переменные на уровне подключенного файла (не в функциях) будут доступны из родителя после инклуда

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.